# Double Square Brackets in my Javascrip Arrays within localStorage?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, local-storage

I have managed to get data registering to my `localStorage` as arrays, however I have three queries:

1. Why are there double square brackets around my array?
2. How do I change the `name` field to the respective html ID?
3. Data returning as `undefined` when I try to retrieve it from the `localStorage`?

The output I am looking for in my `localStorage` is:

```
bookings: [
           [0]{fname: "John", lname: "Smith" }
           [1]{fname: "Jane", lname: "Doe" }
          ]
```

But I am currently getting:

```
bookings: [
           [0][{name: "fname" value: "John"},{name: "lname": value: "Smith" }]
           [1][{name: "fname" value: "Jane"},{name: "lname": value: "Doe" }]
          ]
```

I understand how to change the name value when items are hardcoded but I am initialising an empty array in my JS and not sure where the error is, I have tried assigning a value to the array [0] but then it doesn't register anything. I have also tried the `data.flat()` method which does nothing.

The issue is my next step is to amend and delete items so I need to try and understand the structure. Currently I am getting undefined when I try to get data from storage, I have provided my remove function (currently to show) below, I know it is wrong but I think the issue is to do with how I am storing the data. Sorry I have asked so many questions on this but I am new to JS and still learning. I am struggling with searches as there are so many variations of Javascript and getting a lot of answers relating to C# or Python which isn't helping.

Here is my code:

```
//var bookings = []; 
var bookings = localStorage.getItem("bookings");

$("#submit").click(function () {

    //bookings = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookings")) || [];
    bookings = (bookings) ? JSON.parse(bookings) : [];
    var newBooking = $("#regForm").serializeArray();

    bookings.push(newBooking)

    var json = JSON.stringify(bookings);
    const newData = bookings.flat();
    window.localStorage.setItem("bookings", json);
});

$("#remove").click(function () {
    var strBookings;
    var i;

    strBookings = localStorage.getItem("bookings");
    //document.write("<p>" + strBookings + "</p>");

    bookings = JSON.parse(strBookings);
    for (i = 0; i < strBookings.length; i++) {
        document.write("<p>" + strBookings[i].value + "</p>");
    }
    //localStorage.removeItem('bookings');
});
```

Form

```
<form id="regForm" name="regForm" class="col-sm-6">

    <div class="row">
        <input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" name="fname" required>
        <input type="text" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" name="lname" required>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>

</form>
```

Show

```js
//var bookings = []; 
var bookings = localStorage.getItem("bookings");

$("#submit").click(function () {

    //bookings = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookings")) || [];
    bookings = (bookings) ? JSON.parse(bookings) : [];
    var newBooking = $("#regForm").serializeArray();

    bookings.push(newBooking)

    var json = JSON.stringify(bookings);
    const newData = bookings.flat();
    window.localStorage.setItem("bookings", json);
});

$("#remove").click(function () {
    var strBookings;
    var i;

    strBookings = localStorage.getItem("bookings");
    //document.write("<p>" + strBookings + "</p>");

    bookings = JSON.parse(strBookings);
    for (i = 0; i < strBookings.length; i++) {
        document.write("<p>" + strBookings[i].value + "</p>");
    }
    //localStorage.removeItem('bookings');
});
```

```html
<form id="regForm" name="regForm" class="col-sm-6">

        <div class="row">
            <input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" name="fname" required>
            <input type="text" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" name="lname" required>
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>

    </form>

   <button id="remove" value="Remove">Show</button>
```

Comment: a) you're doing `const newData = bookings.flat();` but then never use `newData` but store the json derived from the original (nested) `bookings` b) you use `bookings.push(newBooking)` (where `newBooking` is an array, should be named `newBookings`) instead of `bookings.push(...newBookings)` or `bookings = bookings.concat(newBookings)`

Comment: `newBookings` doesn't store anything on my end.. Can you also explain the `(...newBookings)` as is why we use the ... or do we? I've seen it mentioned a few times.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: Ah okay thanks, unfortunately it still does not work as newBookings is undefined?

Comment: `var newBookings = $("#regForm").serializeArray();` Notice I added an `s` to the variable name since it stores multiple new bookings.

Comment: Okay it is now adding them without the square brackets, but adding each element into its own index rather than the same one?

Comment: Oh wait I misunderstood your question. You're using [`serializeArray`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) but are actually looking for an object. You will need to accumulate the key-value pairs in the array into an object, then `.push` that to your bookings.

Comment: Okay, I will go try and learn to do that haha. Something to do with mapping? Yes..

Comment: Do you have any suggestion as to how I can replace the `name` and `value` attributes to my IDs?

Comment: Create an object, loop over the array you get from `serialiseArray`, create properties in the object.

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't need this to work with arbitrary forms, just don't use `serialiseArray` at all and write `const newBooking = { fname: $('#fname').val(), lname: $('#lname').val() };`

Comment: Oh thats how you write it! I was trying to do that earlier to save myself the hassle but I couldn't figure out the syntax. That sounds much simpler for what I need it for so I will try that. Thanks for letting me know the other method though as it's always good to learn.

Comment: Now it isn't registering any data.. Do I still have to initialise an empty array of bookings at the beginning, then newBookings for my object data, then push newBookings?

Comment: I got it working! Thank you so much @Bergi